# R - how two have two y-axes with zeroes aligned in the middle of the plot

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting two graphs on the same plot. Each one has a different ylim, and I would like to have the zeroes aligned in the middle of the plot.

This is my code:

```
# data
 time <- seq(0.1, 10, by = 0.1)
 det_rot <- runif(100, min=-100, max=100)
 vel_mag <- runif(100, min=0, max=5)

# first plot
 smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(time, det_rot, spar=0.20)
 plot(time, det_rot,lwd=2,
           ann=FALSE, las=2, pch="",  ylim=c(-100,250)) # , pch=""
 lines(smoothingSpline, lwd=2, col="red")

 par(new=TRUE)

# second plot
 smoothingSpline2 = smooth.spline(time, vel_mag, spar=0.20)
 plot(time, vel_mag, 
      xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",pch="", ylim=c(0,6))
 lines(smoothingSpline2, lwd=2, col="blue",)
 axis(4)
```

See the plot:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some minimal, reproducible example data. We can't see the `J2_arrow_only_2N` dataset and it takes lots of time to make up fake data that fits your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the code

Comment: Awesome, you'd be surprised at how infrequently someone actually fulfils the request for usable example data. Thanks!

Comment: a dput of your data can be directly eval'd in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix: change ylims to c(-250, 250) and c(-6,6) respectively.